# php nao reconhece o comando mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysqli

estou executando um coigo via cmd e ele começou a apresentar esse erro
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/futebol/crawler/php/crud/Conect.php:6
Stack trace:

## 0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/futebol/crawler/php/crud/Conect.php(13): conn('root', '', '127.0.0.1', 'futebol')

## 1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/futebol/crawler/autoload.php(3): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...')

## 2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/futebol/crawler/instatscout/Rastrear_metchs_tournament.php(7): autoload('php/crud/Conect...')

## 3 {main}

thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/futebol/crawler/php/crud/Conect.php on line 6
codigo

```
if (!function_exists('conn')) {
    function conn($usuario,$senha,$host,$bd)
    {

        $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha, $bd);
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        return $conn;
    }
}
$conn = conn( "root",'',"127.0.0.1","futebol");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se instalou o lamp baixando do site Xampp então é só ir no php.ini e descomentar a linha:

```
;extension=mysqli.so
```

Para (remove o `;`):

```
 extension=mysqli.so
```

**Se for php7** provavelmente pode estar assim:

```
;extension=mysqli
```

Para (remove o `;`):

```
 extension=mysqli
```

Salve a edição, após salvar o `php.ini` reiniciei o lamp:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Eu não lembro se tem um `restart` a muito tempo não uso xampp, só uso o que vem pelo repositório, mas você pode experimentar:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Só pra constar, o Xampp se eu não me engano tem um painel que dá pra reiniciar o Apache, mysql e outros por ele mesmo, sem precisar de comandos.

Comment: Sim o xampp tem o xampp control panel para abrir o painel, cujo nome do ficheiro não me lembro mas fica na mesma pasta da instalação. De qualquer forma também da para iniciar por comando com ./xampp start ou até indicando o que pretende iniciar com ./xampp startapache